# Looping through content control and their tags

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking to loop through all of the content control tags in a word doc and shows them in a MsgBox. I have this simple piece of code, and I have the MS Word Object library active, but it keeps giving me a "Object doesn't support this property or method". I got this bit of code from a previously answered question, but it is not working for me. Any ideas of what I'm missing here?

```
Sub NameCheck()


Dim wrd As Word.Application
Dim pc As Word.Document
Dim CC As ContentControl



Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set pc = wrd.Documents.Open("V:\AarealUSA\Common\ACC Templates\Test.docx")

  For Each CC In pc
    MsgBox CC.Tag
  Next CC

End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each CC in pc.ContentControls`?

Comment: Thank you @BigBen. That did the trick